# Swift MVVM Design Pattern

Tags: swift

I have a MVVM project. I am fetching JSON data in the ViewModel. How can I reload the

1. Table view defined in View.swift.

```
import UIKit

final class UsersListScreenView: UIView {
    
    lazy var userListTable = UITableView()

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        addSubviews()
        setUpConstraints()
        setUpViews()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    
    private func addSubviews() {
        [userListTable]
            .forEach {
                addSubview($0)
                $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            }
    }
    
    private func setUpConstraints() {
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            userListTable.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            userListTable.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            userListTable.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 36.0),
            userListTable.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -36.0),
            userListTable.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1)
        ])
    }
    
    private func setUpViews() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

2. Receiving JSON in ViewModel.swift

```
final class UsersListScreenViewModel {
    
    var userList = [UsersList]()
    weak var vc: UsersListScreenViewController?

    let urlToFetchData = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
    
    func getUsersList() {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: urlToFetchData)!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let userResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode([UsersList].self, from: data)
                        self.userList.append(contentsOf: userResponse)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            userListTable.reloadData()
                        }
                    }catch let err {
                        print(err.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }
```

How can I invoke the userListTable.reloaddata from the ViewModel.swift file.

Comment: What does a `UIView` subclass have to do with a table view?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I invoke the userListTable.reloaddata from the ViewModel.swift file

You don’t. That would violate separation of powers. Typically the view model sends a signal to which the view is subscribed; thus the view hears that new data is ready and fetches it and reloads the table.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to send an "onAppear" event to the view model (aka action or intent) in the view life cycle event `onAppear` (SwiftUI) resp. `viewDidAppear` (UIKit) to the view model to support the view model to make informed actions. Based on internally maintained state, the view model may then start to load or update data, or activate a subscription to listen to data updates. Simultaneously the view independently *observes* the state changes that the view model has generated. These represent the single source of truce how the view should render itself.

The use of an "onAppear" event (or similar life-cycle events) send from the view is optional. A view model may independently start loading data when it will be created, for example. It might be completely sufficient that the view starts observing the view model (more precisely, the view model's *view state*).

So, what you need is a View Model which exposes an observable view state, and a View or View Controller which *observes* it. Once the view state changes, you call a handler in your View (View Controller). The concrete implementation for UIKit would probably map the view state to a UITableView conform data source and update the table view with the difference of the new and old data.

Your View Model also exposes an API where you can send "events" (aka actions, intents) from the view to the view model as mentioned above, or to handle user actions on UI controls.

Note that the view state is immutable.